# Laravel 8: How to get value increment in multiple columns with a single where statement?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause

I have a table called **Post** where there are three separate columns to count **post_like**, **post_dislike**, **post_react**.
Whenever user presses the like or dislike button value in the respective column and also value in **`post-react`** column will increment by one.
I use where statement to increment the value of like/dislike.

```
Post::where('id', $id)->increment('post_like');
```

I want to combine the operation of post_react column in the same statement.

```
Post::where('id', $id)->increment('post_like', ['post_react' => DB::raw( 'post_react + 1' ),]);
```

The statement fails to execute all together.

```
**Error on log**
[2020-12-17 07:54:07] local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\DB' not found at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravelblog\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\PostsController.php:143)
[stacktrace]
```

**Note:**

```
Post::where('id', $id)->increment('post_like', ['post_react' => \DB::raw( 'post_react + 1' ),]);
```

or

```
Post::where('id', $id)->increment('post_like')->increment('post_react');
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure your column `post_like` is INT typed ?

Comment: "doesn't work" ... so what does happen

Comment: @VincentDecaux yes it increments when I use the first statement. post_like, post_dislike and post_react are all bigint.

Comment: @code-mon oh ok, I missreaded, so your increment works, just the second error. But do you read the error at least ? It can't be more clear ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux that's all I get in the error log*** [2020-12-17 08:40:01] local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\DB' not found at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravelblog\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\PostsController.php:144)

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it seems you forgot to add the **DB facade**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: I get this error now. `[2020-12-17 08:42:22] local.ERROR: Non-numeric value passed to increment method. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Non-numeric value passed to increment method. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravelblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php:2919)` but all the three columns are bigint.

Comment: Try this

DB::raw( 'post_react, +, 1' )